# Elastic Search: boost "nicer" terms

Tags: elasticsearch

Imaging the following, search term "brown fox".

All documents do have another field, called it alternate name.

This field sometimes conatins nice terms like "Animal" or "Fox". Sometimes it contains "not nice" (or human readable) terms like ED2314 or 1231-234-D.

What the "not nice" things have in common they have a "high" amount of numbers or they a really not human language WIPSDIFOW.

Any ideas on "boost" or sort the nicer terms to the top?

**Update 2016-01-24**
Thank you for the question.

The search will be done on the field "name" for example. The "alternate name" field won't be queried with the user input. It is just a field that is relevant for sorting. The user likes to see it in the result list, but with the explained sorting / boosting. 
Thx

Comment: I'm unclear on the issue.  If the searcher is searching for "brown fox", they will match any `alternate_name` that has "brown" or "fox" (in the normal case), scoring matches with both terms higher.  (If they specifically search for a "not nice term" (like a part number) they ought to match that specific term.)  I assume you're seeing 'irrelevant-seeming' matches... are they coming from 'not-nice' terms in `alternate_name`? Can you give examples?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I added more information to the question.  The field "alternate name" is relevant for sorting / boosting. Not for the query it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some limited script-based [scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) and [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) (with a performance penalty).

But if this is the first of (likely) many requests to "tweak scoring" based on unstructured data, you'd be better-served annotating your data (pre-indexing) to codify scoring logic more clearly in the index.

---

I.e.  Add fields like `alternate_name.dictionary_words`, `alternate_name.non_dictionary_words` (and maybe `alternate_name.dictionary_word_composition_percent`) and use a dictionary to enrich the data set just before you load it.

The advantage here is that the scoring strategy appears in the data, query performance (including the "percent" field in your scoring or sorting criteria) is better, and you'll have the ability to use the human-readable terms in isolation for future features (facets/autocomplete/spellcheck).   Plus the non-human-readable terms will be more accessible for future analysis (when, eg, you had enough information to annotate/separate-out say "part_numbers")

Answer (score 0):

Using the bool query you can boost nice terms (query clauses) encapsulating them into the `should` key:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {  
                    "field": {
                        "query": "User input"
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": [
                { "match": {
                    "field": {
                        "query": "Animal"
                    }
                }},
                { "match": {
                    "field": {
                        "query": "Fox"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

To control the relevance of the nice terms, you may use the `boost` option as well:

```
...
{
  "match": {
    "field": {
      "query": "Fox",
      "boost": 3
    }
  }
}
...
```

See [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated my question. It was maybe misleading, I am looking for some sorting / boosting on the result. Not the queried fields itself.

Comment: consider keeping the "alternate field" in the `should` option and the "name" field in the `must` option, thus only documents matching "name" field will be retrieved and documents containing "nice terms" in the "alternate field" get higher scores.